# Where to initialize MongoDB connection in Django projects?

Tags: django, mongodb, pymongo

I wonder where I should initialize my MongoDB connection in my Django projects.

Currently I am initializing the client and db before my view functions in views.py:

```
import pymongo

from django.conf import settings


client = pymongo.MongoClient(settings.MONGO_URI)
db = client.get_default_database()


def some_view(request):
    pass
```

However I also need to use MongoDB in my models.py in conjunction with Django signals. What do you suggest?

Comment: Is this a main database that you'll be saving to or a separate database that you'll occasionally be reading from?

Comment: I will basically use MongoDB to read cached model data. Therefore I am using django signals post_save and post_delete to update MongoDB collections.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe `settings.py`? Or even root `__init__.py`? Then you can import `client` and `db` everywhere you need it.

Answer (score 1):

I've decided to use project/mongodb.py (same folder as settings.py)

```
import pymongo

from django.conf import settings


client = pymongo.MongoClient(settings.MONGO_URI)
mongodb = client.get_default_database()
```

I am using two different settings files for local and production. Therefore, this approach makes it possible to use environment dependent settings, while enabling me to access mongodb variable from anywhere in the project.